# Maximal degree and chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Given a positive integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$, is there a positive integer $k\in{\mathbb N}$ such that

> for every finite, simple, undirected graph $G$ with $\Delta(G) = n$ we have $\chi(G) \leq k$

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$k=n+1$. For the coloring with $n+1$ colors, use induction on the number of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

By Brooks's theorem, one can take $k=n$ when the graph (assumed to be connected) is not isomorphic to $K_p$ (the complete graph on $p$ vertices), and $C_p$ (the cycle on $p$ vertices), $p$ odd.

Comment: to be rigorous, this is for connected graphs

Comment: You're right ! I corrected my message.